# Как использовать Form в Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

Я создал Form в QT как Widget и мне нужно чтобы он появлялся при нажатии кнопки и им могло управлять главное окно. Имеется ввиду чтобы Form появлялся поверх главного окна

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Вы хотите, чтобы по нажатии кнопки у вас открывалось немодальное окно диалога Form? Form у вас - это только форма (файл с расширением ui) или полноценный класс виджета?

Comment: Вероятнее всего вы создали ui файлик формы, ui файл это просто xml документ, в котором описаны элементы формы, и который далее можно, либо редактировать в дизайнере, либо в коде подключать через `setupUi()`. А чтобы сделать полноценный самостоятельный виджет, который просто используется путём создания объекта класса, при добавлении, вам нужно выбрать `Qt Designer Form Class`.

Comment: Хорошо,спасибо.